# New to Darktable, unable to import from Canon R5

Tags: import

I have Darktable running in Ubuntu but cannot import photos direct from camera.  With Darktable running I connect camera and The R5 appears in the import pane.  When I click on "mount camera" this message appears "failed to initialise'Canon R5' on port'usb:001,009' likely causes are: locked by another application, no access to devices etc".  I have searched on this problem but nothing relevant came up.  When I switch camera off it disappears from the import pane so it's obviously recognised but I cannot find any reference to this in the manual.  I can use terminal but have no idea how to investigate this problem.

Comment: It is usually a lot faster to import the pictures from the card (using a SD card adapter, or the built-in SD card reader).

Comment: Good point for SD but CFexpress card reader is expensive to buy.  Hence reason to download :)

Comment: Do you have WiFi enable on the camera? If you wish to connect the camera via USB you need to turn WiFi off. You also need to have Canon's EOS Utility installed on the computer.

Comment: Running Ubuntu, Canon stuff only runs on Win.

Answer (score 1):

Tried connecting camera without Darktable running and noticed that two instances were showing as mounted.  I clicked on one unmount icon, both icons disappeared.  I then started Darktable and clicked on mount.  Simple when you know how, shame it doesn't mention this in the manual.

Comment: To my mind it is the answer, the solution to the problem is to conect the camera in the correct order.  Which I outlined.  What would you suggest is the correct solution?  Also my apologies to Darktable, this is mentioned in the manual but I missed the significance when reading.

Answer (score 1):

You could also compartmentalise the operations – that's what I'd do. Don't treat the camera as a card-reader – remove the memory card from the camera and use a dedicated card-reader to get the files onto your internal drive. Then you can do what you like with them. No need to complicate things, IMO. Camera for photography, computer for file operations and editing.